# Why does my method no longer work now that I've added constructors?

Tags: java

I was watching a java tutorial, and once he changed his class to have constructors instead of defining each variable in each object, all his methods still worked.

I changed it to constructors, and now all I get is 0 for my method.

```
public class Volume3Lesson4Exercise1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        groceryStore houstonStore = new groceryStore(534, 0.99, 429, 0.87);
        groceryStore seattleStore= new groceryStore(765, 0.86, 842, 0.91);
        groceryStore orlandoStore=  new groceryStore(402, 0.77, 398, 0.79);     

        System.out.println("\nSeattle store revenue: ");
        seattleStore.calculateGrossRevenue ();

        System.out.println("\nOrlando Store Revenue: ");
        orlandoStore.calculateGrossRevenue ();

    }

}

class groceryStore {
    int apples;
    double applePrice;
    int oranges;
    double orangePrice;

    groceryStore(int a, double ap, int o, double op){
        a= apples;
        ap= applePrice;
        o= oranges;
        op= orangePrice;
    }

    double calculateGrossRevenue(){
        double grossRevenue;

        grossRevenue= ((apples * applePrice)+ (oranges * orangePrice));

        return grossRevenue;

    }
}
```

On the following code, the revenue returns the number 0 as the gross revenue.  Why?  The numbers are still the same as they were before, but just are now constructors and not individual variables of each object.

Comment: Change `a = apples` to `this.apples = a`. Same for the other fields, of course. The usual convention is to use the same name for the argument and the field, and to use `this.apples = apples`.

Comment: I tried that and it worked.  For some reason on the video someone made a few years ago, he didn't add the word this and it still worked.

Comment: What matters is not the `this`keyword. What matters is that you initialize the field with the value of the argument, instead of initializing the argument with the value of the field.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you learn Java from a good book or the official Java tutorial, rather than random youtube videos. Youtube is for lolcats.

Comment: Good advice! In general, to learn something, one needs to approach it in an organized way, via a book or a comprehensive seminar. An isolated video may help, but it will probably prove inadequate.

Comment: It wasn't a YouTube video.  It is a course from CodeLearner.com.  A couple videos later it they should the this keyword, but he implied it wasn't required.  He did it without it and it still worked for some reason.

Comment: I see why it worked now when he did it.  He put apples = a and not a = apples.  I didn't know it made a difference.  I'm a math person and thought they both were equal as they would be in algebra.

Comment: The `=` symbol in programming usually (and definitely in `Java`) does not denote equality, but assignment of a value to another. It typically means "store the value appearing on the right side, to the memory location denoted by the variable on the left side".

Answer (score 2):

The assignment of the values in the constructor has to change order, i.e.

```
groceryStore(int a, double ap, int o, double op) {
    apples = a;
    applePrice = ap;
    oranges = o;
    orangePrice = op;
}
```

Doing so would mean that the values of the parameters passed to the constructor would be saved in the instance variables (apples, applePrice etc.), which is the intended behavior. The assignments shown in the original code have no effect, so the instance variables will keep their default value, which is `0` for all numbers.

For more clarity, the `this` keyword should be used for all instance variables, i.e.

```
groceryStore(int a, double ap, int o, double op) {
    this.apples = a;
    this.applePrice = ap;
    this.oranges = o;
    this.orangePrice = op;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does that mean? I assigned all the values at the top when I created each object.  So, why are they all still 0?  This isn't making sense.

Comment: They remain `0`, because no value is actually assigned to the instance variables. The assignment always happens to the parameter on the left of the `=` symbol. See which variables you have at the left of the `=` in the constructor. For example, you pass `534` for `a` in the first call and inside the constructor you overwrite this by `apples`, since you define `a = apples` (meaning "assign to `a` the value of `apples`"), thus `534` is never assigned to `apples`; instead, `a` gets the value of `apples`, which is the default value, i.e. `0`, since no value has been assigned before.

Comment: The video that taught about constructors didn't use the word this and they all still worked.   I added the word this and they all worked.

Comment: As per my answer and per the comments you have already received, the `this` word is for clarification purposes. Adding it to your original code will not make it work. If you write `a= apples;` you assign `apples` to `a`, not `a` to `apples` as you should. Exactly the same happens even if you write `a= this.apples;`. The correct statement would be `apples = a;` or (even better) `this.apples = a;`. The order is the important thing here, not the presence of the `this` keyword.